# Using wildcards within VBA for Microsoft Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, wildcard

Lets start this off by saying that my knowledge of code is limited at best. I generally understand the concepts, but was never very good at implementing them. That said here is a snippet of code from a project that fell in my lap.

```
Option Compare Database
Private Sub Form_Current()
If IsNull(Me![OPT-78 (5900EL)]) Then
    Me![OPT-78 (5900EL)].Visible = False
    Me![OPT-78 (5900EL) Label].Visible = False
Else
    Me![OPT-78 (5900EL)].Visible = True
    Me![OPT-78 (5900EL) Label].Visible = True
End If
If IsNull(Me![OPT-78 (7900EL)]) Then
    Me![OPT-78 (7900EL)].Visible = False
    Me![OPT-78 (7900EL) Label].Visible = False
Else
    Me![OPT-78 (7900EL)].Visible = True
    Me![OPT-78 (7900EL) Label].Visible = True
End If
If IsNull(Me![OPT-152 (4310B)]) Then
    Me![OPT-152 (4310B)].Visible = False
    Me![OPT-152 (4310B) Label].Visible = False
Else
    Me![OPT-152 (4310B)].Visible = True
    Me![OPT-152 (4310B) Label].Visible = True
End If
```

This is located inside the a form in the "current" event. Now I know that wildcards could limit all these if then else statements down to a simple elegant single if statement solution, but I haven't been able to get them to work. I've tried *, %, __, and ?, but no luck. There are MANY more if else statements that will have to be written so I'm hoping there is a cleaner solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps a `Select` statement can be worked in to shorten your code a bit?

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by creating a Sub to handle setting the visibility:

```
Sub SetVis(controlName as String)
   Dim vis as Boolean
   vis = Not IsNull(Me.Controls(controlName))
   Me.Controls(controlName).Visible = vis
   Me.Controls(controlName & " Label").Visible = vis
End sub
```

Then you can drive that sub from a loop, maybe by looping over the form's Controls collection to find the ones of interest.

```
Dim c
For Each c in Me.Controls
    'some If statement here to see if this is a control you're interested in
    'Might also want to check that the control type is a textbox so you can
    '  skip the labels
    If c.Name like "OPT*" And Not c.Name like "*Label" Then
        SetVis CStr(c.Name)
    End if
Next c
```

Or a simple loop based on a fixed array of names:

```
Dim c
For Each c In Array("OPT-78 (5900EL)", "OPT-78 (7900EL)", "OPT-152 (4310B)") 
    SetVis CStr(c)
Next c
```

Comment: Note (also @Nogg ) that if a label is attached to its textbox, you only need to set the textbox visible/invisible, the label is automatically set accordingly.

Comment: Thanks guys. 
@ Andre: I found that the label follows the textbox with the turning visibility off, but when I flip it back on later in the form it doesn't. Don't know why.

@Tim: I was looking at the code you posted and I was wondering if this will allow me to grab the name of the textboxes with different names. In other words I'm try to grab text box OPT-1, OPT-12A, OPT-435 and have them flip on and off based on whether the value inside is null. I'm not real familiar with how to set up loops and whiles. I took a very basic programming class about 8 years ago. ;)

Comment: See my edits above (all untested but should give you the general idea)

Comment: Thanks Tim,
With the array solution wouldn't I have to continue to add manually the "OPT"s? I've got the visibility to work, but the thing I'm really trying to get is basically for the code to search for anything named "OPT*". There will be potentially thousands of "OPT"s as well as other areas where I will have a similar issue. The "OPT"s are just textboxes. Not sure if that helps or not. I really appreciate your help on this. I'm an illustrator trying to code lol.

Comment: I realize I'll be adding the text boxes manually to some extent, but I was hoping that the code would have to be altered for each one.

Comment: See my edit in the loop over the Controls collection

Comment: Ah cool! Thank you. That should do it. It is weird I can read it and generally understand what is going on I'm just awful at understanding how to write it! :)